# What is an appropriate response header for language filter fail?

Tags: http-status-codes

I'm checking for vulgar language via an http request. If the string in question turns out to contain a bad word, what response Status-Code should I send back? I considered just `200` (along with `badWord`, or something).

Edit: There's other work that will not occur in the request if the string contains a bad word(s). On the other hand if there is not a bad word(s) then it will complete the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`2xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3) status code indicate that the server received, understood and accepted the request. It doesn't seem to be the case though.

In your question, it's not clear what *bad word* means, but if you intend to refuse the request due to a client error, you should consider [`4xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) status codes. Assuming that the *syntax* of the message is correct but the *semantic* is not, you could return [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) to indicate that the message cannot be processed by the server:

> [**11.2.  422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.